# PgfPlots bar with missing data causes columns to be "misplaced"

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, graphs

I looked for a similar problem here in SE but I couldn't find it. It's just driving me crazy :|

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt, pdflatex]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Warsaw}  % Madrid, CambridgeUS, default, Pittsburgh
\useinnertheme{rounded} % rectangles
}

%\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section{Graphs}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,    
    xmax=12,
    style={font=\footnotesize},
    symbolic x coords ={1, 2, 4, 6, 12},
    legend entries={A, B},
    legend style={draw=none,at={(1.38, 0.5)}, anchor=east, font=\scriptsize},
    legend columns=1]
\addplot table [x=X,y=A1] {TableGraphs.dat};
\addplot table [x=X,y=B1] {TableGraphs.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ scale only axis, height=0.25\textheight, width=0.65\linewidth, max space between ticks=40, 
    ybar,
    style={font=\footnotesize},
    xmax=12,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    symbolic x coords ={1, 2, 4, 6, 12},
    legend entries={A2, A3},
    legend style={at={(1.38,0.5)},anchor= east, draw=none,font=\scriptsize}, 
    legend columns=1,
    unbounded coords=jump] 
  \addplot table [x=X,y=A2] {TableGraphs.dat}; 
  \addplot table [x=X,y=A3] {TableGraphs.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale only axis, height=0.3\textheight, width=0.65\linewidth, max space between ticks=40,
    symbolic x coords ={1, 2, 4, 6, 12}, 
    style={font=\footnotesize},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmax=12,
    legend entries={B2, B3},
    legend style={at={(1.38,0.5)}, anchor=east, draw=none, font=\scriptsize},
    legend columns=1] 
    \addplot table [x=X,y=B2, unbounded coords=jump] {TableGraphs.dat}; 
    \addplot table [x=X,y=B3, unbounded coords=jump] {TableGraphs.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale only axis, height=0.25\textheight, width=0.65\linewidth, max space between ticks=40, 
    ybar,
    font=\footnotesize,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    symbolic x coords ={1, 2, 4, 6, 12},
    legend entries={A4, A5},
    legend style={at={(1.48,0.5)},anchor= east, draw=none, font=\scriptsize}, 
    legend columns=1] 
    \addplot table [x=X,y=A4, unbounded coords=jump] {TableGraphs.dat}; 
    \addplot table [x=X,y=A5,unbounded coords=jump] {TableGraphs.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scale only axis, height=0.25\textheight, width=0.65\linewidth, max space between ticks=40, 
    symbolic x coords ={1, 2, 4, 6, 12},
    font=\footnotesize,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    legend entries={B4, B5}, 
    legend style={at={(1.48,0.5)}, anchor=east, draw=none, font=\scriptsize}, 
    legend columns=1] 
    \addplot table [x=X,y=B4,unbounded coords=jump] {TableGraphs.dat}; 
    \addplot table [x=X,y=B5,unbounded coords=jump] {TableGraphs.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the data I used:

```
X   A1  B1  A2  B2  A3  B3  A4  B4  A5  B5
1   6.8333333333    27.25   42.25   3.2991666667    69.4166666667   0.3233333333    37.25   0.7733333333    42.1666666667   0.19
2   14.3333333333   91.1666666667   90.5    3.1366666667    181 0.32    17.3333333333   0.6166666667    18.8333333333   0.165
4   24.3333333333   148.3333333333  160.6666666667  3.1933333333    303.6666666667  0.33    11.6666666667   0.8066666667    12  0.2233333333
6   56  349.5   387 3.405   900.5   0.335   5.5 0.96    4.5 0.245
12  125 1195    1301    3.5 nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

And here is page 2 of the output:
[image]
and page 3

[image]

The problem is in the bar chart in the first picture (2nd page of the output) and in the bar graph of the second picture (3rd page of the output).

There's a bar missing. The table represent running times and gaps for algorithms. For the larger instances, on the right of the x axis, there are missing values. But both the bar chart start only with 1 red bar, while they should have 2 bar for each x value and in the first graph have only a blue bar at the end, while in the second they should stop at 6, since both values associated to 12 are missing.

Here are the same graphs, in the same order, in Excel
[image]

[image]

Am I missing something? thanks.

Comment: Add `enlarge x limits=true` to axis options and you'll see.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Does the order with which I add it to the arguments of axis count?

Comment: It works with version 1.10. I get identical results

Comment: Ok. I have installed native TeXLive2013 from TL's site. It comes with psgfplot 1.10, which is uptodate methinks.
It doesn't work.
I tried with different parameters, copying back the examples I posted here.
Nothing.... :'(
Thanks anyway, I think I'll be using Excel...